# Proofing Slater's condtion iterative?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

If I have a convex optimisation problem for an engineering application of the standard form:
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x} \quad & f(x)\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & g_i(x) \leq 0 \\
  & h_j(x) = 0    \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$
with $f(x), g_i(x)$ being convex functions and $h_j(x)$ being linear functions.

And now I want to verify that Slater's conditon holds:
If there exists a $x^*$ relative interior point of the convex set such that $g_i(x^*) < 0\ \forall i$ and $h_j(x^*) = 0\ \forall j$.

Can I just iterate over random point, for example, in a python script and as soon as one point would fulfill all convex strict inequalities and linear equations I have verified that Slater's condition is given and strong duality holds?